# android-update line between two rotating rectangles

Tags: android, graphics

after i draw line between 2 fixed points on two different rectangles i need to rotate them.The problem is that my line is not updated, it stays on the same x1,y1 x2,y2. How to make line to follow this rectangle?

If any of you have any example code or something that can help, it would be great!
Thanks!

I dont think that i will need OnValidateUpdate tho solve this.
This is my example code to demonstrate this problem:

Object that i want to draw:

```
public class Object {
    private int xPos;
    private int yPos;
    private int width;
    private int height;        
    float xDistance = 0f;
    float yDistance = 0f;
    double angleToTurn = 0.0;       
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private Rect rect;
    private Paint paint;
    private Point point;
    Paint p = null;



public Object(int xPos, int yPos){          
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;          
        this.width = 300;
        this.height = 100;          
        matrix = new Matrix();          
        rect = new Rect(xPos,yPos,xPos + width,yPos + height);          
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL); 
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        p = new Paint();
        p.setStyle(Style.FILL); 
        p.setStrokeWidth(15); 
        p.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        point = new Point(this.getxPos(), this.getyPos()+this.getHeight());

    }    
    public void rotate(float xEvent, float yEvent){         
         xDistance = xEvent - this.xPos;
         yDistance = yEvent - this.yPos;
         int angleToTurn = ((int)Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(yDistance, xDistance)));
         matrix.setRotate((int)(angleToTurn),xPos,yPos + height/2);     

    }       
    public void draw(Canvas c){         
        c.save();
        c.setMatrix(matrix);

        c.drawRect(rect, paint);            
        c.drawPoint(point.x,point.y,p);

        c.restore();            
    }

    public Point getPoint() {
        return point;
    }
    public void setPoint(Point point) {
        this.point = point;
    }
    public Matrix getMatrix() {
        return matrix;
    }
    public void setMatrix(Matrix matrix) {
        this.matrix = matrix;
    }
    public int getxPos() {
        return xPos;
    }
    public void setxPos(int xPos) {
        this.xPos = xPos;
    }
    public int getyPos() {
        return yPos;
    }
    public void setyPos(int yPos) {
        this.yPos = yPos;
    }
    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }
    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
```

GameView class where i draw 2 rects:

```
 public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private GameloopThread gameloopThread;     
    float downx,downy,upx,upy;
    private Object object,object1;
    Line line; 


    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        gameloopThread = new GameloopThread(this);
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

        object = new Object(500,500);
        object1 = new Object(800,700);

        line = new Line(object.getPoint(),object1.getPoint());
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Canvas canvas  = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        onDraw(canvas);
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        gameloopThread.setRunning(true);
        gameloopThread.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry = true;
        gameloopThread.setRunning(false);
        while(retry){
            try {
                gameloopThread.join();
                retry=false;
            }catch(InterruptedException e){

            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,int height) {

    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent( MotionEvent event) {
        float x = 0f,y=0f;
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            downx = event.getX();
            downy = event.getY();

        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) { 
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();
            object.rotate(x, y); 
            object1.rotate(x, y);          
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

        }                       
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas); 
        canvas.drawColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        if(object != null)
            object.draw(canvas);
        if(object1 != null)
            object1.draw(canvas); 

        if(line != null){           
            line._drawLine(canvas);         
        }

    }

 }
```

Line class that should connect two rectangles (i made class for it but it is not needed)

```
 public class Line {

  private Point point1,point2;
  private Paint p;
  Matrix m;
  public Line(Point p1,Point p2){
    this.point1 = p1;
    this.point2 = p2;

    p = new Paint();
    p.setStyle(Style.FILL);    
    p.setColor(Color.RED);

    m = new Matrix();

 }

 public void _drawLine(Canvas c){       
     c.setMatrix(m);
    c.save();       
    c.drawLine(point1.x, point1.y, point2.x, point2.y, p); 
    c.restore();
 }

 public Matrix getMatrix(){
    return m;
 }

 }
```

I would like to use Matrix object if possible to achieve that.There is also MainActivity and Thread class but I dont post them because thay are not relevant to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution I can just use Matrix.mapPoints, save them and just redraw line !

Answer (score 0):

You can use ValueAnimator to animate the rectangles. On each

```
onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation)
```

you can invalidate or re-draw the line with the new position.

Comment: Hi tx for your answer. I can try that but I would like to do that without ObjectAnimator.I edited my question and posted code.